# SQL dependency event fires on Alter Database but not on Table changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldependency

Working on someone else's code where they've instituted a SQL Dependency event (SQL 2008). Not something I'm terribly familiar with so was just doing some reading and some testing.

The event is called CustomerServicesTable_OnChange and so is presumably meant to fire whenever the customerServices table is changed. However when the DB is changed through code (we're using Entity Framework) the event is not firing.

Out of curiosity I fired up SQL Server Manager and tried running queries against the table directly to see what would happen. Running UPDATE, INSERT or ALTER queries against the table didn't cause the event to fire.

To check that SQL dependency had been enabled I then ran the following commands against the database, supposedly the first step in enabling the service:

```
ALTER DATABASE customers SET SINGLE_USER with rollback immediate
alter database customers set enable_broker
ALTER DATABASE customers SET MULTI_USER
```

To my surprise running these commands caused the event to fire!

So it looks as though the dependency is working against either the database as a whole, or table(s) in the DB other than CustomerServices. Can anyone suggest a way forward to help me determine exactly what the problem is?

EDIT: I have discovered that it's not the ALTER DATABASE commands which are causing the event to fire, but the fact that SET SINGLE_USER causes an error. Doesn't help me with the problem much though.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this one worked out:

1) The database owner needs to be set to a SQL Server account instead of a Windows Admin account.

2) The watch service (i.e. the SQL command issued to start the notification service) needs to be set up on the same user account as will be used to make the database updates you're watching for.

I did a bunch of permissions work, but I think those are the two key issues to making it work.

Answer (score 0):

Read this first to understand how SqlDependency works: [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/).

Possibly the notifications are piling up in [`sys.transmission_queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190336.aspx) and the `transmission_status` would indicate why this happens.

A shot in the dark: the dbo is mapped to invalid SID:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::customers to sa;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However it appears as though support for Notifications has been removed in SQL Server 2008, which is what we're using. It looks like the error popping up is a red herring.

Comment: Query Notifications were **not** removed from SQL Server 2008 nor any later version and are not on the deprecation path. You are talking about Notifications Services, which is a completely different, unrelated feature. ASP Cache dependency and SqlDependency use Query Notification and have no relation whatsoever to Notification Services.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I have read your article and been through the MS tutorial step-by-step, replicating the code in it's entirity just to ensure that I'm doing exactly the same as MS suggest but no dice: the service just isn't working. And if it's a permission, wouldn't the suggested CanRequestNotifications() function in the tutorial catch the problem?